# Back Button in Android Cause application to crash when navigation history is null

Tags: android, cordova

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if(web1.canGoBack() == true){
                web1.goBack();
            }else{
                finish();
            }
            return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

I am using following function in my android application built using PhoneGap. The application has a WebView.

When Back button is pressed it will navigate back. But when navigation history is null it will crash the application. And the error log is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.cordova.DroidGap.onKeyUp(DroidGap.java:1057)
```

How can i fix this?.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the condition if the history is null then on clicking the back button use 
finish(); .

Comment: Hi hetal,but it might be  crash app when it gets null

Answer (score 0):

Override in your activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if(navigatinHistory == null){
   Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
   finish();
}
}
```

Comment: how can i get the navigationHistory?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that onKeyUp has code that implies appView member has been set in DroidGap.

As it has not been set, the application crashes when the KeyUp event occurs.

Two solution :

1. Override the onKeyUp method
2. Call the init() method in onCreate method

I would suggest you the second one, which is better.

Comment: It's Overridden, but do you call super.onKeyUp in your onKeyUp child method. If yes, problem is the same. But as I told, it's not the best solution for me, prefer the second one.

Comment: i just called the function init(); in the onCreate function. Still the problem not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In Phonegap applications, you should listen to the event "**backbutton**" to handle the navigation and exit the app when you need it to.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function() {

    // ...

    navigator.app.exitApp(); // call it to exit the app

}, false);
```

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton